# php-amqplib libarary working on command prompt but not on browser

Tags: rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I have the same code which work when I run with command prompt. But it throws below error when I try running it with browser.

I have used php-amqplib. My code simple make connection to RabbitMQ Queue and send a message into queue. The credentials are correct as I am able to run the same file in command prompt.

> Notice:  iconv_strlen(): Detected an illegal character in input string
> in
> /var/www/html/php-amqplib/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php
> on line 338
>
> Notice:  iconv_strlen(): Detected an illegal character in input string
> in
> /var/www/html/php-amqplib/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php
> on line 338
>
> Notice:  iconv_strlen(): Detected an illegal character in input string
> in
> /var/www/html/php-amqplib/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php
> on line 338
>
> Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException:
> Error reading data. Received  instead of expected 7 bytes in
> /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:242 Stack
> trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(149): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(106): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(508):
>
> PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(555):
>
> PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(0)
>
> ## 4 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(217):
>
> PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(0, 0)
>
> ## 5 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(328):
>
> PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame(0)
>
> ## 6 /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(205):
>
> PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->w in
> /var/www/html/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 242

Answer (score 6):

I discovered the problem (and the solution) when I ran the command:

- > php composer.phar install

and I received these errors:

```
  Problem 1
- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.3 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.

  Problem 2
- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.3 -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/php-amqplib[v2.6.3].
```

---

My problem - missing PHP extensions (bcmath, mbstring) from my system - was solved by simply installing them:

- > sudo apt-get install php-bcmath php-mbstring

These extensions were used by some code called by a Rabbit consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the heartbeat value from 0 to 60 sec.

Comment: Can you explain bir more where to change/set value. Thanks